# Why is this check true whether or not the interrogated radio buttons are checked?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, html-select

I have this jQuery to check whether one of the two radio buttons above has been checked when the user selects a dropdownlist

```
$(document).on("change", '[id$=ddlPayToIndividual]', function () {
    . . . // unrelated code elided for brevity
    var $uscitizenyes = $('[id$=rbUSCitizenOrPermResY]');
    var $uscitizenno = $('[id$=rbUSCitizenOrPermResN]');
    if (!$uscitizenyes.checked && !$uscitizenno.checked) {
        alert('You must select above whether payee is a US Citizen or Permanent Resident or not');
    }
});
```

I would imagine that I should only see the alert if *neither* radio button is checked, but I see it no matter what when I change the selection in the DropDownList/html selector. Why?

Comment: Did you walk through in developer console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.checked` is a DOM property, but `$uscitizenyes` and `$uscitizenno` are jQuery objects, not DOM elements. You need to use the jQuery method. Use:

```
if (!$uscitizenyes.is(":checked") && !$uscitizenno.is(":checked")) {
```

Since jQuery objects don't have the `.checked` property (in general, jQuery doesn't use properties, it does almost everything with methods), your code always thinks both boxes are unchecked.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, so I'll just add that the reason the alert is always shown is that since `$uscitizenyes.checked` is undefined, and `!undefined` is true, the if statement is equivalent to `if(true && true)`